# Looping output as new input many times (50+) in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, loop

I want to run focal statistics on a raster, then run focal statistics (same configuration/setup as the first focal stat.) again on the output, and again on the new output, and again, and again.

Maybe 50 times.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an arcpy script with a for loop. Afterwards you can use this script in the ModelBuilder.

I was not able to test it, but it should be something like this.

```
# Name: FocalStatistics_Ex_02.py
# Description: Calculates a statistic on a raster over a specified
#    neighborhood.
# Requirements: Spatial Analyst Extension
# Author: ESRI

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/sapyexamples/data"

# Set local variables
inRaster = "your_data"
neighborhood = NbrRectangle(10, 10, "CELL")

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute FocalStatistics
outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics(inRaster, neighborhood, "MINORITY","")

for i in range(0,50):
    tmp_result = FocalStatistics(outFocalStatistics, neighborhood, "MINORITY","")
    outFocalStatistics = tmp_result

# Save the output 
outFocalStatistics.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/focalstatout")
```

Comment: As the answerer said this could then be used in the model builder. A completely valid solution to OPs question if it works.